# Pandas filter values with low number of decimal

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'start': [50, 100, 50000, 50030, 100000],
                   'end': [51, 101, 50001, 50031, 100001],
                   'value': [1.00, 2.1234567, 3.01, 4.12345, 5.456789]})
```

I would like to filter the values of columns 'value' and keep only values with decimal greater then two:

```
start   end        value
100     101        2.1234567
50030   50031      4.12345
100000  100001     5.456789
```

How to filter the column by decimal size?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) with [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

Cast your `df` into `str`.
Split the `value` column on `.` and pick the 2nd part.
Then get the length of the decimal part.
Pick the rows with length > 2.

```
In [639]: df[df['value'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[1].map(len).gt(2)]
Out[639]: 
    start     end     value
1     100     101  2.123457
3   50030   50031  4.123450
4  100000  100001  5.456789
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by converting to strings, but in real data because float accuracy this solutions should failed:

```
df = df[df['value'].astype(str).str.extract('.(\d+)$', expand=False).str.len().gt(2)]
print (df)

    start     end     value
1     100     101  2.123457
3   50030   50031  4.123450
4  100000  100001  5.456789
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to ignore nan values and to keep them in the dataframe?

Comment: @honeymoon - Sure, use `df = df[df['value'].fillna('0').astype(str).str.extract('.(\d+)$', expand=False).str.len().gt(2) | df['value'].isna()]`

Comment: @honeymoon - or only `df = df[df['value'].astype(str).str.extract('.(\d+)$', expand=False).str.len().gt(2) | df['value'].isna()]` should work

Comment: Last question, I am struggeling to replace the values with decimal less then two with Nan. Is this possible?

Comment: @honeymoon - what means `less then two with Nan` ? Do you think if only one NaN between non NaNs values? Like `1, nan,7, nan, 8` match, if `1, nan, nan, 7, nan, 3` then match only last NaN?

Comment: Example of the dataframe above: 'value': [Nan, 2.1234567, Nan, 4.12345, 5.456789]}

Comment: Instead of removing the  values with decimal less then two, replace the values with Nan

Comment: @honeymoon - Use `df['value'] = df[''value].mask(df['value'].astype(str).str.extract('.(\d+)$', expand=False).str.len().gt(2))`